# Chaining where clauses returns 0 objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

For a schoolproject i have to make a simple website where i have to search members based on what the user types and then display these members. I have 5 properties to look for (first and lastname, sex, level, club). They have to work together but some might be null.

```
public List<Lid> ZoekLeden(string deelVoornaam, string deelNaam, string geslacht, string niveau, string deelClubNaam)
{

    var filteredleden = context.Leden.Include(lid => lid.ClubNrNavigation)
        .OrderBy(l => l.Naam)
        .Where(l => l.Voornaam.Contains(deelVoornaam))
        .Where(l => l.Naam.Contains(deelNaam))
        .Where(l => l.Geslacht.Equals(geslacht))
        .Where(l => l.Niveau.Equals(niveau))
        .Where(l => l.ClubNrNavigation.Naam.Contains(deelClubNaam))
        .ToList();

    return filteredleden;
}
```

Sadly it keep returning 0 and i dont know why.

I tested each individual property and they all return the proper members. But the moment i use multiple they always return 0. Does anyone know why this happends and how i can fix it?

Comment: it is difficult to say without seeing your data, but I get the feeling that you actually would like to search for multiple properties using a single where clause and combining the search conditions using the `AND` or `&&` operator. If you say that you use multiple then some of them are `null` ? or do you use all of them?

Comment: @MongZhu Some of them might be null indeed. I havent tried using && i will try that now.

Comment: We don't put "solved" in the question.  Accept one of the answers or post your own instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public List<Lid> ZoekLeden(string deelVoornaam, string deelNaam, string geslacht, string niveau, string deelClubNaam)
{
    IQueryable<Lid> filteredleden = context.Leden
                        .Include(lid => lid.ClubNrNavigation);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(deelVoornaam))
        filteredleden = filteredleden.Where(l => l.Voornaam.Contains(deelVoornaam));

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(deelNaam))
        filteredleden = filteredleden.Where(l => l.Naam.Contains(deelNaam))

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(geslacht))
        filteredleden = filteredleden.Where(l => l.Geslacht.Equals(geslacht))

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(niveau))
        filteredleden = filteredleden.Where(l => l.Niveau.Equals(niveau))

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(deelClubNaam))
        filteredleden = filteredleden.Where(l => l.ClubNrNavigation.Naam.Contains(deelClubNaam));

    return filteredleden.OrderBy(l => l.Naam).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, your solution keeps running in a loop for the property that was filled in. C# then stops it and returns 0 again

Comment: @JeremyBlekkink - sorry, but I don’t understand your comment.

Comment: update, i changed IEnumerable to IQueriable and now it works. Thanks again for you great help!

Comment: @JeremyBlekkink - updated the answer to reflect your comment, though IMHO it shouldn’t make a difference, but glad it is working on your end.

Answer (score 0):

You're chaining .Where() which is the equivalent of if(bool && bool && bool). Instead, I think you need if(bool || bool || bool)

So the LINQ statement should be:

```
    var filteredleden = context.Leden.Include(lid => lid.ClubNrNavigation)
    .OrderBy(l => l.Naam)
    .Where(l => l.Voornaam.Contains(deelVoornaam)
        || l.Naam.Contains(deelNaam)
        || l => l.Geslacht.Equals(geslacht)
        || l => l.Niveau.Equals(niveau)
        || l => l.ClubNrNavigation.Naam.Contains(deelClubNaam)
    )
    .ToList();
```

If you really do need the &&'s, then theres probably nothing in your dataset that meets all the criteria in the chained .Where()s

Comment: HI thanks for your help. The reason i need && is because they have to work together. if i use || i get multiple answer

example: 
thomas delf, thomas thomas gerits, thomas veld, sarah veld
I just want to get thomas veld so i need first and last name.

Comment: @JeremyBlekkink Since you need and instead of or, it's likely that nothing in context.Leden.Include(lid => lid.ClubNrNavigation) meets all the criteria of the following 5 Where calls.

Comment: but when the criteria do match i still get 0 result. that is the problem i am trying to solve

Comment: @JeremyBlekkink I'm suspicious of the .Include then. It would be worth debugging and looking at the value of var debug = context.Leden.Include(lid => lid.ClubNrNavigation).ToList() and checking that to see if there is anything you think should be in the actual output. My guess is that the .Wheres are fine and the initial set contains less values than you think it does.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem was solved with the other persons answer.